# Localhost Connection Interruption Issue with Express Server and Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, express, graphql, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I want my phone, on the same Wi-Fi as my computer, to access my computer's Express server at its localhost. In the past, I used ngrok or a proxy on my web server to achieve this, but it was complex and costly.

Now, I've set up a direct proxy on my Express server to serve the computer's localhost. Here's the essential code from `server.ts`:

```js
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import express from "express";

import schema from "./schema";
import resolvers from "./resolvers";

import http from 'http';

import UsersAPI from "./datasources/users";

const serviceAccount = require("serviceAccount.json");
const databaseURL = "https://my-app.firebaseio.com";

const globalServerApp = admin.initializeApp(
  { credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount), databaseURL },
  "server"
);
const globalDataSources = {
  usersAPI: new UsersAPI(globalServerApp),
};

const initServer = () => {
  const app = express();
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: schema,
    resolvers,
    dataSources: () => {
      return globalDataSources;
    },
    uploads: false,
    // Enable graphiql gui
    introspection: true,
    playground: true,
    context: async ({ req }) => {
      return {
        request: req,
      };
    },
  });
  server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: "/", cors: true });
  
  if (process.env.HOME === "/Users/mememe") {
    const serverHttp = http.createServer(app);

    const host = '0.0.0.0';
    const port = 5001;
    serverHttp.listen(port, host, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
    });
  }
  
  return app;
};

export default initServer;
```

It works, sort of.

I run the server with `firebase emulators:start --only functions`, which executes the firebase function that fires the server:

```js
const graphqlServer = initServer();
exports.graphql = functions.https.onRequest(graphqlServer);
```

It loads:

```js
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions
⚠  ui: Emulator UI unable to start on port 4000, starting on 4048 instead.
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/.../server/functions" for Cloud Functions...
✔  functions: Using node@18 from host.
i  functions: Loaded environment variables from .env.
Serving at port 8642

Server is running on http://0.0.0.0:5001

✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: graphql, auth, compressImage, email, addToIndex, updateIndex, deleteFromIndex, backupDeletedRecord.
✔  functions[us-central1-graphql]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-app/us-central1/graphql).
✔  functions[us-central1-auth]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-app/us-central1/auth).
✔  functions[us-central1-compressImage]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-app/us-central1/compressImage).
✔  functions[us-central1-email]: http function initialized (http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-app/us-central1/email).
i  functions[us-central1-addToIndex]: function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running.
i  functions[us-central1-updateIndex]: function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running.
i  functions[us-central1-deleteFromIndex]: function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running.
i  functions[us-central1-backupDeletedRecord]: function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running.

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://127.0.0.1:4048/               │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ 127.0.0.1:5001 │ http://127.0.0.1:4048/functions │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Emulator Hub running at 127.0.0.1:4400
  Other reserved ports: 4500
```

The server runs on `http://0.0.0.0:5001`, which is essentially localhost.

I've set my computer's IP to `192.168.1.200` manually. This means that I should be able to access the GraphQL UI hosted on the computer by going to `http://192.168.1.200:5001/my-app/us-central1/graphql`.

When I start the server, it initially connects successfully. However, as soon as the functions load (right after it prints Server is running on `http://0.0.0.0:5001`), it disconnects.

If I visit `http://localhost:5001/my-app/us-central1/graphql` **on the computer** after the functions load, it opens the GraphQL UI. After doing this, refreshing the webpage on the phone loads the GraphQL UI.

I believe that I need to somehow wait for the functions to fully load and only then run `serverHttp.listen`. Is there a way to listen to the emulators start event (the moment we get "All emulators ready!")?